# In-app product details in different languages using the google play billing library

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase

I'm using the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/package-summary) version 3 to fetch available in-app products.

After calling `querySkuDetailsAsync` on the `BillingClient` object, I'm correctly getting the [SkuDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails) for each product.

In the Google Play Console, I translated the product details into multiple languages. However, I'm getting the details only for the main language.

**How can I fetch the in-app product details in different languages?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will receive the details translated in the language that you set in the device settings.
Try to change the language of your device and you should see that the product details will be fetched in the correct language.

Comment: It might actually pull the language from the Google Play account since it requests the data from Google Play. Updating the system language and making sure Google Play is in the desired language may be necessary

Comment: @JensV From my tests changing the system language setting is enough. If you have the same Google Play account on 2 different devices with 2 different languages, it will fetch the product details in the language of the device

Comment: Fair enough. I was just assuming and didn't actually test it. +1

Comment: Indeed, changing the system language will fetch the corresponding product details. I wish I had the possibility of querying for a specific language. Maybe it will be added in the future as an attribute for SkuDetailsParams. Anyway, it is good enough as it is right now